# Visual studio 2017 format document wrong on javascript on an aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, formatting

When I clicked Format Document on an aspx page, some JavaScript was formatted wrong like following screenshot.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbNYC.png)

If I do the same thing in VS 2013. this part will be formatted fine.

Anyone has a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Press `Control` + `K D` several times. That will format the code.

Comment: The format will become worse.